# How to connect Dialogflow bot with localhost web-app which access data from locally running api and Database

Tags: botframework, bots, googlebot

I am very new at Dialogflow, I want to integrate bot in Angular-webapp which is running in intranet/localhost where based on intent I have to form a query and access localhost database.

I have already worked on Microsoft LUIS and integrated with node-js.
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs.

But I'm not finding the similar thing for Dialogflow.

These samples app I can execute as localhost perform certain operation based on intent returned from LUIS.

And With the samples app, I can connect to localhost databases too.

This time I thought to use Dialogflow. I have created and working bot.
But I want to write some API in localhost with localhost database.
And perform operation based on intend/entity returned from Dialogflow.

Summary:

I don't want to keep database and web-app on the internet. It can be in intranet or localhost.
I agree to have only dialogflow on a cloud.

Is there any library similar to Microsoft botBuilder samples ,so, I can leverage Dialogflow in the localhost web app, localhost APIs and localhost database based on intent/entity returned from Dialogflow.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't entirely clear, but it sounds like you want to use Dialogflow to do the Natural Language Understanding component - determine which Intent was triggered with what parameters, and return this information to you.

If so, you probably want to look into Dialogflow's [Detect Intent API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#detect_intent_and_agent_apis).